# Getting the MOTION data from Kinect for a BVH file

Tags: kinect

I'm trying to write bvh files to animate models using Kinect. So far, I managed to build the hierarchy of the skeleton, but I have problems understanding how to get the Motion part.
Since it's a bvh file, I only need to retrieve the rotation matrix (Rz, Rx, Ry) for each bone, but I have to take into account the relative angles of the parent bones. I'm a bit lost in this part, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: may be this [How to parse a bvh file to a skeleton model made in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699028/2521214) will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can find several implementation for BVH files such as http://kinect-bvh-mocap.software.informer.com/.